# Scala Array view 'flatmap'

Tags: scala

I'm trying to implement an idiomatic in-place quicksort in scala. To do this, I'm recursing over views instead of (left, right) index pairs. However, I'm running into a problem taking a view from a view.

```
Array(1, 2).view => IndexedSeqView[Int, Array[Int]]
Array(1, 2).view.view => IndexedSeqView[Int, IndexedSeqView[Int, Array[Int]]]
```

and so on. This leaves me unable to recursively partition views of views of views of some base array, because my recursive function doesn't know what type to expect. Is there a way to take views such that the view of an IndexedSeqView[Int, Array[Int]] is also an IndexedSeqView[Int, Array[Int]]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of function of [mutable.IndexedSeqView](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.IndexedSeqView) that return other views. For your case, i'd assume `splitAt` is what you want.

Try making your whole scala quicksort deal in `IndexedSeqView`s and then provide a convenience wrapper for sorting `Array`s.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make my function work on any view over a sequence of Ints by replacing

```
def quickSort(arr: IndexedSeqView[Int, Array[Int])
```

with

```
def quickSort(arr: IndexedSeqView[Int, _]).
```

But I would prefer a function mapping

```
IndexedSeqView[A, C[A]]
```

to some sub-view

```
IndexedSeqView[A, C[A]]
```

if such a function exists